# Como Agrupar os resultados de um Select em duas tabelas -- SQL

Tags: sql

Bom tenho duas tabelas  o TBInfo e a tabela TBPrograma

```
CREATE TABLE TBInfo(
    Ip VARCHAR(20),
    HostName VARCHAR(50),
    Mascara VARCHAR(15),
    Gataway VARCHAR(15),
    Win VARCHAR(50),
    Versao VARCHAR(8),
    Hd VARCHAR(11),
    Memoria VARCHAR(8),

);

CREATE TABLE TBProgramas(
    Ip VARCHAR(20),
    NomePrograma VARCHAR(255),
);
```

E gostaria que quando usasse um  SELECT ficasse assim

```
Ip           | HosteName | Programas
192.255.3258 | USER-PC   | VisualStudio,Google Chrome
```

Comment: Utilize a cláusula GROUP BY com uma função de agregação que concatene os nomes de programa, tipo string_agg(expression, delimiter) ou a equivalente de seu SGBD na junção de suas tabelas.

Answer (score 2):

Um possibilidade é utilizar a cláusula inner join:

```sql
SELECT
  TBInfo.ip,
  HostName,
  NomePrograma
FROM TBInfo
INNER JOIN TBProgramas
  ON TBProgramas.ip = TBInfo.ip
```

Outra possibilidade é agrupar e concatenar o Nome do Programa:

**MySQL - 5.1.73**

```sql
SELECT
  TBInfo.ip,
  TBInfo.HostName,
  GROUP_CONCAT(TBProgramas.NomePrograma) AS Programas
FROM TBInfo
INNER JOIN TBProgramas
  ON TBProgramas.ip = TBInfo.ip
GROUP BY (TBInfo.ip);
```